# No puedo comparar 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo 2 arrays:

```
var a = [11];
var b = [5];

var c = [a,b];
```

Y uso el metodo sort() para ordenarlos.

```
c.sort(function(a, b){if(a>b){return -1}; if(a<b){return 1;} return 0;});
```

Y al ver como quedo me queda asi:

```
c[0][0] = [5];
c[1][0] = [11]
```

E intente hacer esto de otra forma:

```
var comparacion = (lesta[0][0]>lesta[1][0]) ? a = true : a = false;
```

Y cuando voy a ver que es comparacion...

```
comparacion = true;
```

Ya intente varias cosas, como lo puedo solucionar? Y porque pasa esto? Agradeceria una respuesta.

Comment: no entendi si queres compararlos porque los ordenas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar 2 arrays en Javascript puedes usar el siguiente método que comprueba valor por valor y la longitud

```
var a = [5,5,5];
var b = [5,5,5];

function arrayEquals(a, b) {
    return Array.isArray(a) &&
        Array.isArray(b) &&
        a.length === b.length &&
        a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}
```

Lo que te ocurre es porque la comparación

```
a === b
```

Solo será true si ambos arrays tienen la misma referencia en memoria, no compara sus valores internos como si hace el código mostrado arriba

Comment: Gracias, lo pude resolver!